# UML Activity diagram - Input Activity Parameter Node

Tags: uml

Is it allowed to connect the `Output Pin` of an `Action` to the `Input Activity Parameter Node` of an `Activity` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [UML Activity Diagrams: Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409465.aspx). It seems to indicate that you can.